# Как создать Lambda layer (в Amazon AWS) на python?

Tags: python, lambda, amazon-web-services

Пишу несколько функций Lambda в Amazon Web Service (AWS), новичок в AWS.
Использую питон (Python 3.8).

Хочу некоторые общие функции и константы на питоне вынести в общий модуль (библиотеку).
Для этого есть, как я понял, так называемые Layers.
Создал Layer, загрузил в него файл lib.zip, в котором (без подпапок) лежит мой файл с общими функциями, назовем его lib.py. Больше ничего в архиве нет.
Подключил слой к лямбда-функции.
После этого в lambda_function.py пишу:

```
import lib
```

однако при тестировании возникает ошибка, что модуль lib не найден.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, надо было в архиве добавить папку python.

У меня все получилось, когда я внутри архива расположил файл lib.py в папке python подпапке lib.
А в lambda_function.py импортировал следующей строкой:

```
from lib import lib
```

Возможно, подпапка здесь лишнее, но может и такой кейс кому-то пригодится.